# Sublime Shortcut: Key-Binding to put each HTML attribute on a new line inside <> tag

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, key-bindings, sublime-text-plugin

I've scoured the internet and can't seem to find a solution.

I'm looking for a keybinding/shortcut that will change this....

```
<div id="foo" class={bar} />
```

to this...

```
<div
  id="foo"
  class={bar}
/>
```

Comment: have you tried https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HtmlTidy and the http://api.html-tidy.org/tidy/quickref_5.0.0.html#indent-attributes setting?

Comment: Not available for ST3, but thanks because I started looking at broader code formaters and found that [SublimeJsPrettier](https://github.com/jonlabelle/SublimeJsPrettier) will reformat each attribute to new lines if there are more than 5.

Comment: Have you tried to write a Sublime snippet for this?  If so, where did you get stuck?  http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html

Comment: Has anyone found a solution with works with Sublime Text 4? #st4